# Read messages from queue from remote computer

Tags: c#, msmq, user-accounts

We're trying to implement MSMQ in our applications and we face the next problem: Our application(console application) starts under a local machine (machine1) user account in the domain X.

On the same domain there is another machine (machine2) and on this machine is the queue. On the domain X there is an user account with admin rights and this user has full control on the queue, but when our application starts, because it runs under the local account, it doesn't have the rights to read messagess.

Is there any solution on how to fix this issue only from the code? We can't change the user account that our console application is using. I'm thinking to use impersonation as the last solution.

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Both private and public queues should allow you to do this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772532.aspx

Have a look at the section under Public and Private queues.

Public queues should be available to any domain account, including machine accounts.

Private queues allow anyone to write, but need particular permission to read.

Comment: Hi Ben, I've read this article and here it states that I should give permissions "Receive Message" to my user. But the problem is that my user is not a domain user, it's a local user and this user from machine1 and it is not visible on machine2 to add this user to the security tab of the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to read messages only by impersonating. Here is my code:

Impersonating context wrapper:

```
 public class WrapperImpersonationContext
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

        private string m_Domain;
        private string m_Password;
        private string m_Username;
        private IntPtr m_Token;

        private WindowsImpersonationContext m_Context = null;


        protected bool IsInContext
        {
            get { return m_Context != null; }
        }

        public WrapperImpersonationContext(string domain, string username, string password)
        {
            m_Domain = domain;
            m_Username = username;
            m_Password = password;
        }

        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public void Enter(out string result)
        {
            if (this.IsInContext)
            {
                result = "not in context";
                return;
            }
            m_Token = new IntPtr(0);
            try
            {
                m_Token = IntPtr.Zero;
                bool logonSuccessfull = LogonUser(
                   m_Username,
                   m_Domain,
                   m_Password,
                   LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                   LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                   ref m_Token);
                if (logonSuccessfull == false)
                {
                    result = "logon failed";
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = "logon succseeded";
                }
                WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(m_Token);
                m_Context = identity.Impersonate();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                result = "exception: " + exception.Message;
                // Catch exceptions here
            }
        }


        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public void Leave()
        {
            if (this.IsInContext == false) return;
            m_Context.Undo();

            if (m_Token != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(m_Token);
            m_Context = null;
        }
    }
```

Reading messages:

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:servername\PRIVATE$\queue_name");
WrapperImpersonationContext context = new WrapperImpersonationContext("domain", "username", "password");
context.Enter(out result);
Message msg = queue.Receive();
context.Leave();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't impersonate a valid domain account, you would have to allocate the 'anonymous logon' special account permissions on the queue. The 'everyone' special group won't work as that only covers accounts recognised by the domain. Accounts local to your machine are foreign to the domain and not included.

Comment: Hi John, due to security issues, 'anonymous logon'  is not an option for us, so the security team created a domain user that had rights only on the queue and we've used impersonation to read messages.